# Spring boot multiple controllers and extending the url

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

This is controller 1:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/clusters")
public class ClusterController {

    @Autowired
    private ClusterService clusterService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getAllClusters(Model model){

        List<Cluster> clusters = this.clusterService.getAllClusters();
        model.addAttribute("clusters", clusters);

        return "clusters";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/clusterInfo", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getCluster(@RequestParam("id") Integer id, Model model){
        Cluster cluster = this.clusterService.findClusterById(id);
        model.addAttribute("cluster", cluster);

        return "testcluster";
    }
```

Controller 2:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/requirements")
public class RequirementController {


    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String getRequirements(){

        return "requirements";
    }
}
```

First I see all clusters. After that I can click on a button on the site to see an individual cluster (method 2 from controller 1).

When I see an individual cluster, I want to click on a button to see the requirements linked to that cluster. The method for that is in Controller 2.

I want to have the following url path when going from controller 1 to 2.

http://localhost:8080/clusters

http://localhost:8080/clusters/clusterInfo?id=1

http://localhost:8080/clusters/clusterInfo?id=1/requirements

This is the button that I use to go from url 2 to 3.
More

It doesn't work and gives me an error. My question is, how can I go from controller 1 to 2 with the specified url path and retrieve the id=1 in controller 2?

It's my first project so I don't know much about Spring Boot and Thymeleaf.

Answer (score 1):

`?` marks the beginning of query string parameters and according to URI RFC standards, you cannot specify path after query string parameters.
I'll suggest to instead change the URIs to:

```
http://localhost:8080/clusters/<clusterId>/clusterInfo
Ex: http://localhost:8080/clusters/1/clusterInfo
```

And

```
http://localhost:8080/clusters/<clusterId>/requeriments
Ex: http://localhost:8080/clusters/1/requirements
```